# How join columns with null value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

**Hi please help me. How join 3 columns with null values?.**

```
SELECT [item],[Prox],[z], [item]+[Prox]+[z] as result FROM [FIELD$];
```

**Result.**

[image]

Comment: Use `COALESCE(column, '')` function.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Shall we guess? SQL-Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As concatenating multiple strings with at least one null value results in `NULL` you may use `coalesce` to solve this:

```
SELECT
    [item],
    [Prox],
    [z],
    coalesce([item], '') + coalesce([Prox], '') + coalesce([z], '') as result
FROM
    [FIELD$];
```

`coalesce` is ANSI standard and available in almost all reasonable databases.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT [item],[Prox],[z], COALESCE([item],'')+COALESCE([Prox],'')+COALESCE([z],'') as result 
FROM [FIELD$];
```

**Explanation:**

`COALESCE` evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially does not evaluate to NULL.

i.e., If `[item]` is `NULL`, then `COALESCE([item],'')` will return an empty string.

**Other alternatives:**

Instead of `COALESCE(ColName,'')`, you can use:

1. `ISNULL(ColName,'')` for `SQL Server`.
2. `IFNULL(ColName,'')` for `MySQL`.
3. `NVL(ColName,'')` for `Oracle`.

Answer (score 1):

IN SQL Server 2012, you can use CONCAT function:

```
SELECT [item],[Prox],[z], concat([item],[Prox],[z]) as result FROM [FIELD$];
```